# Vampire vs werewolf novel with both on the cover (with non-matching shadows)

Tags: story-identification, novel, vampire, werewolf

I'm looking for the name of a particular novel. It's a vampire vs werewolf novel, with the main protagonist being a werewolf. I do know the book is written in the first person narrative. It's set in modern times in a high school.

Only other clue I vaguely remember was the cover. Two people were facing each other, one male, one female. **The female vampire had the shadow of a were wolf, the male werewolf had the shadow of a vampire.**

Comment: I'm sure you can come up with more info for us. [How to ask a good story-ID question?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question).

Comment: Was this an adult novel (with sexy scenes)? Were the Vampire and Werewolf a couple? Did they fight each other? Why were they fighting? Were they humans who'd become vampires/werewolves or races unto themselves? When was it set (contemporary/medieval/urban/futuristic)? What were the main character's names? Can you remember any specific events in the novel? Why was this novel especially memorable to you?

Comment: As far as the content, it wasn't adult, as far as I can remember.

Comment: The main character's name and the Antagonist's name escape me, but I do know it's set in Highschool.

It's a modern setting, too.